# study the monotony of $g(x)=f(\sin^2(x))$

Tags: calculus

What I know: $f({3\over4}) = 2$ and $f^\prime({3\over4})=-4$.

Also I know that $f^\prime(\sin^2(x))$ is strictly decreasing with a single zero at $x=2$.

How can I study the monotony of $g(x)=f(\sin^2(x))$ and finding the extremes in the domain $x \in ]0,\pi]$?

Comment: Have you tried to compute $g'(x)$?

Comment: If I tried: $g^\prime(x) = 2\cos(x)\sin(x) f(\sin^2(x)) + f^\prime (\sin^2(x))$

Comment: So $g'(\frac\pi3)=\sqrt3-4$ and $g'(\frac{2\pi}3)=-\sqrt3-4$.

Comment: On what interval is $f'(\sin^2(x))$ supposed to be decreasing? It can't be all of $(0,\pi)$, since $f'(\sin^2(x))=f'(\sin^2(\pi-x))$.

Comment: The book says Yes, but I don't understand how it can be done. Why $\pi \over 3$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hypothesis is not so clear.  But based upon some understanding, here I have given some argument. At least it will help to improve the hypothesis.

$g$ has a local minimum at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

To see this, note that $g'(x)=2\sin x\cos xf'(\sin^2x)$(by Chain rule). Since $f'(\sin^22)=0$ and strictly decreasing, $f'(\sin^2x)\geq0$ for all $x\in[0,2]$.

Now, both $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are non-negative on the interval $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Hence $g'\geq 0$ on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$. Also $\cos x$ is negative on  $[\frac{\pi}{2},2]$. Therefore, $g'\leq 0$ in $[\frac{\pi}{2},2]$.

Hence $g$ is increasing on $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$ and decreasing on $[\frac{\pi}{2},2]$. This implies that $g$ has a local minimum at $\frac{\pi}{2}$.